# Angular2 testing with nested dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angularfire2

I have a test for a component ("DashboardComponent") that uses a service ("ProgramService"). ProgramService uses another import, "AngularFire", but the component does not - yet my test for the component is failing with the error: "No provider for AngularFire!". The same error does *not* occur when just running the application.

The dependency tree *should* be: DashboardComponent -> ProgramService -> AngularFire

But it *appears* to be:

DashboardComponent -> ProgramService -> AngularFire

AND

DashboardComponent -> AngularFire

My test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { ProgramService } from '../program.service';

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent ],
      providers: [ ProgramService ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Do i really need to add all nested dependencies (i.e. AngularFire) to my component test(s)? That seems like a very bad idea

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProgramService } from './program.service';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  // Stuff
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [ProgramService],
  declarations: [AppComponent, DashboardComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### test.ts

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};


Promise.all([
  System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
  System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
])
  // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
  .then(([testing, testingBrowser]) => {
    testing.getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
      testingBrowser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
      testingBrowser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );
  })
  // Then we find all the tests.
  .then(() => require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
  // And load the modules.
  .then(context => context.keys().map(context))
  // Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
  .then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);
```

Comment: We need your karma config and the content of your module declaration to help you better. Just pasting the code that fails isn't enough.

Comment: I don't use AngularFire, but I don't see any configuration for the injection and configuration of AngularFire anywhere in your testing files. In a general case, it seems you need to mock that service as it's not relevant to the testing of your component's test.